# How to create an instance in MainWindow and use it in another class

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a serious problem, I'm trying to create an instance in the MainWindow class like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     AppWindow = this;
     CalenderBackground background = new CalenderBackground(Calendar);
}
```

I need this istance in the MainWindow because the class CalenderBackground have a method for refresh a previous date inserted into the Calender, I'm using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/547627/Highlight-dates-on-a-WPF-Calendar) resource.

I want use the object `background` in the class `Fixtures`:

```
class Fixtures
{
     MainWindow.Calendar.Background = background.GetBackground();
}
```

But actually I can't create this, because I can't see the variable `background`, why?

Comment: Because you declared `background` in constructor, so it won't be seen outside of constructor. Declare local variable of type `CalendarBackground` and initialize background in constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the Background object into the Fixtures through the constructor?:

```
CalenderBackground background = new CalenderBackground(Calendar);
Fixtures fixtures;

public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     AppWindow = this;
     fixtures = new Fixtures(background);
}

class Fixtures
{
    public Fixtures(Background background)
    {
        MainWindow.Calendar.Background = background.GetBackground();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tryed, but if I move the variable out the constructor the compiler return me this message: a field initializer can not refer to the property, method or field is not static MainWindows.Calendar

Comment: In MainWindow constructor, why not just do "Calendar.Background = new CalenderBackground(Calendar);"

Comment: public static Calendar Calendar;
the type MainWindow already contain a definition for Calendar. Calendar is an XAML GUI

Comment: Remove "public static Calendar Calendar;"

Comment: I get this error: a field initializer can not refer to the property, method or field is not static MainWindows.Calendar; on CalenderBackground background = new CalenderBackground(Calendar); in particular Calendar (the argument) is underline in red

Comment: The Calendar control is not a static property. You can't reference as 'MainWindows.Calendar'. I would recommend looking at some beginner C# tutorials.

Comment: I solved by inserting CalenderBackground background = new CalenderBackground (Calendar);
within MainWindow constructor

Answer (score 0):

You declared background as a variable within the scope of your MainWindow method. To be able to access it in the Fixtures class you need to pass it as an argument to the constructor and then use it to set a field e.g.:

```
private CalenderBackground _background;

public Fixtures(CalenderBackground background)
{
   _background = background;
}
```

Or you could create a public [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) on your MainWindow and access that from the Fixtures class.

```
public CalenderBackground Background {get; set;}
```